# Can JQL or the JIRA interface give me a table view?

Tags: jira, jql

I need to know if there is a JQL query or a way in the JIRA interface to see a quick table that includes issue number, task name, percentage complete, remarks, priority, and due date. It would be preferable if I could somehow export this to excel. I'm having trouble finding documentation on this sort of JQL. I would appreciate any help or helpful links.

Comment: There's a big export button on the top right corner of the search results. Change the results to the list view and set your columns. etc.

Comment: Oh! Thanks man! I guess, more specifically, do you know if there is a way to change what fields get exported? I really need to know a percentage complete per issue. So maybe how to include an original estimate and time spent? I appreciate you pointing the excel button out... I'm dumb.

Comment: If you save the search as a filter, you can [include specific columns and define the column order](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+Filters#UsingFilters-Definingafilter-specificcolumnorder). If the field you want is not listed in the default results, use the Columns dropdown in the top right corner of the page. And if you want something that's not a field but a calculated value, try a [Scripted Field](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+Fields) using  [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner).